# How do I evaluate a class not on every puppet run?

Tags: puppet

I would like to have a method that only evaluates a particular class once a day at a specific time.  Right now I am running my puppet agent from the cron, but I would like to change it to either run as a daemon, or run more frequently.  The barrier with increasing the frequency is that there is one class that takes about 4 minutes to process, and doesn't need to happen very often.  I am trying to find some method to only evaluate that particular class once a day from cron.

Is there a simple method for me to set an environment variable (`FOO=bar;puppet agent ..`), or add a command line option  (`puppet agent .. --foo bar`) to the crontab that will become a fact I can use in my manifests to include or not include the class?

```
class foobar {
  if 'bar' == $::foo {
    # do the slow stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [schedule](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#schedule) sounds like it'll provide what you're looking for.  First you create a schedule resource that specifies when things can run and how many times in a given period.

```
schedule { "slow":
  range  => "1 - 5",
  period => daily,
  repeat => 1,
}
```

The example above will only be evaluated or run during the hours of 1am and 5am and a maximum of once.  You can remove the `range` parameter and it'll run any time of the day, but again, only once.

On resources, you then specify the `schedule` [meta-parameter](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#schedule) to link them to the above schedule:

```
exec { "example":
  command  => "/usr/bin/foo",
  unless   => "/usr/bin/bar",
  schedule => "slow",
}
```

When you run Puppet with `--debug`, you'll now see the following if it's already been evaluated the given number of times, or the range isn't applicable:

```
debug: /Stage[main]//Exec[example]: Not scheduled
```

If you've got a few resources, you could use [resource defaults](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#resource-defaults) inside the class you're restricting to affect all resources of the same type:

```
Exec {
  schedule => "slow",
}
```

You'd need to do this for each resource type - Exec, File, Augeas etc.

Couple of notes on improving this:

- I don't know a way to apply it to all types of resources in the class
- Applying the `schedule` meta-parameter to a class doesn't appear to work, might be worth raising a bug

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need.  I never noticed ths in the docs before.  Any idea what version of puppet ths feature requires?

Comment: It's been in Puppet for a long time, at least as far back as 0.24.x!  Puppet Labs publish the type documentation for every version so you can check compatibility, change the version number in [this URL](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.6/type.html#schedule).

Comment: So, is this approach recommended over configuring a crontab job from puppet ?

Comment: I don't think I'd replace cronjobs with schedules.  Keep schedules for circumstances like this, when you want to change configuration resources only at certain times of the day, or a limited number of times.  Cronjobs are good at what they do, running commands on a regular interval.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can accomplish this via an [Environment](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/environment.html) declaration. You invoke it on the command-line:

```
puppet agent --environment latetbus
```

You can use it to specify a different manifest in the puppet.conf file:

```
[latebus]
  manifest = $confdir/latetbus/site.pp
```

And even can do different modules that way.

There is also a method for [adding custom facts to facter](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Adding_Facts). This leverages plugins to make work. You create a custom ruby file to check for something:

```
# run_latebus.rb

facter.add("latebus_exec") do
    setcode do
        %x{if [ -e /tmp/run_latebus ] ; then echo "true" ; else echo "false" ; fi}.chomp
    end
end
```

Where the puppet agent invocation script would `touch /etc/run_latebus` before starting `puppet agent`, which is evaluated by Facter during the puppet run.

The .rb file [is placed](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html) in a custom module, specifically in the `lib/facter` directory of the module itself.

Comment: As much as this feels like using a sledge on a finishing nail, it is the most elegant method I can think of. Doing a run against that environment via cron once a day will probably do exactly what he wants.

Comment: I am actually already using environments for testing/production.  I was kind hoping there was some other method.  If no other alternatives are presented, this is what I was probably going to do.